# SQL запрос с 2 таблицами

Tags: sql, postgresql

ДД!
2 таблицы

```
        CREATE TABLE executors
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  email character varying(50),
  signe character varying(50),
  enabled boolean DEFAULT false,
  recording_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  CONSTRAINT executors_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO EXECUTORS(email, signe) VALUES ('test@gmail.com', '12345');
UPDATE EXECUTORS SET enabled=true where email='test@gmail.com';
INSERT INTO EXECUTORS(email, signe) VALUES ('test1@gmail.com', '12345');
UPDATE EXECUTORS SET enabled=true where email='test@gmail.com';

INSERT INTO EXECUTORS(email, signe) VALUES ('test2@gmail.com', '12345');

CREATE TABLE labels
(
  id serial NOT NULL,
  parent_id character varying(15) NOT NULL,
  recording_time timestamp with time zone DEFAULT now(),
  executor_id character varying(15),
  label_title character varying(256) DEFAULT 'label'::character varying,
  label_value character varying(256) NOT NULL,
  label_abv character varying(20) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  label_short character varying(50) DEFAULT NULL::character varying,
  language_id character varying(3) NOT NULL,
  enabled boolean DEFAULT true,
  CONSTRAINT labels_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)

INSERT INTO LABELS (parent_id, executor_id,label_value, label_title, language_id) VALUES ('EXA1','EXA1','Vasya','Name','rus');
INSERT INTO LABELS (parent_id, executor_id,label_value, label_title, language_id) VALUES ('EXA1','EXA1','Petrov','FName','rus');
INSERT INTO LABELS (parent_id, executor_id,label_value, label_title, language_id) VALUES ('EXA1','EXA1','Ivanovich','SName','rus');
```

Parent_id (labels) ссылка на id(executors) 
Причем parent_id содержит не int а varchar в виде 'EXA'+executors.id
EXA - это ссылка на нужную таблицу то есть labels обслуживает не только executors... думаю мысль понятна.

Теперь проблема не могу получить всех executor'ов с имеющими labels (может быть более одного) и не имеющих таковых.
Вот что пытаюсь делать:

```
SELECT e.id, e.email, l.label_title, l.label_value
    FROM
        labels l, executors e   
    WHERE 
        'EXA' = substring(l.parent_id from 1 for 3)::text and
        e.id = substring(l.parent_id from 4)::Integer
```

Выводит только то что имеет labls а надо всех вместе или лучше принудительно создавать label хотя бы один?

Помогите пожалуйста!!!

Это пример с использованием JOIN'ов:

```
SELECT e.id, e.email, l.label_title, l.label_value
    FROM
        executors e RIGHT OUTER JOIN  labels l
        ON e.id = substring(l.parent_id from 4)::Integer 
    WHERE 
        'EXA' = substring(l.parent_id from 1 for 3)::text
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам нужно использовать оператор JOIN, чтобы захватить даже те строки, которые не имеют совпадений. Разобраться с этим оператором помогут эти две ссылки:
[Описание оператора JOIN на википедии](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL))
[Аналогичное описание с иллюстрацией на Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549/what-is-the-difference-between-inner-join-and-outer-join)

В вашем примере используется INNER JOIN (FROM table1, table2 - это просто еще одна форма записи оператора INNER JOIN), который выводит только те записи, для которых найдено соответствие в обеих таблицах.

Вместо этого, вы можете использовать LEFT JOIN, который выберет все строки из левой таблицы, и склеит с соответствующими строками из правой таблицы, если таковые имеются.

Comment: Использую но не получается! Скорее всего не правильно использую: SELECT e.id, e.email, l.label_title, l.label_value
 FROM
  executors e RIGHT OUTER JOIN  labels l
  ON e.id = substring(l.parent_id from 4)::Integer 
 WHERE 
  'EXA' = substring(l.parent_id from 1 for 3)::text